# What did the prefix 'de' mean in: de- + lacere?

Tags: etymology, affixes

> [ [Etymonline :](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=delicious&allowed_in_frame=0) ]  [...]  from Late Latin *deliciosus* "delicious, delicate,"
>   from Latin *delicia* (plural *deliciae*) "a delight, allurement, charm," from *delicere* "to allure, entice," from ***de-* "away"** (see [de-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *lacere* "lure, deceive" (related to *laqueus* "noose, snare;" see [lace](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lace&allowed_in_frame=0)).   [...]

I also read [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deliciae). How does Etymonline's opinion (per the bolded, of 'de-' to mean "away") make sense? If an agent lures or deceives an experiencer, then the agent must cause to agent to approach or near it, and not to become AWAY from it?

Comment: I don't know if anyone knows the exact answer, and I generally suggest against literal reading of prefixes, especially when a word has been borrowed (many times) between languages. I can offer some ideas, though: If someone is lured to something, then they are lured away from something else. You can also read *de-* as "down" or "from above", implying that someone is lured to do something below their values or standards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if, as Lewis & Short suggest, the definition of *dēliciō* is

> **dēlicio, ere, v.** a. *lacio*, the root of *deliciae* and *delecto*, "to allure one from the right way, to entice, delight": *aliquem*, Titin. ap. Non. 277, 17.

then *dē* would make sense. If *liciō* is "to allure" and *dēliciō* is "to allure away from the right way," then *dē* meaning "away" means that the word focuses, as @JoonasIlmavirta's comment suggests, on not just the alluring but the alluring *away* from something.